# How can I share my screen via Skype Beta 5.5?

Tags: skype

How can I share my screen via Skype Beta 5.5? The “+” menu contains only two item: adding another communication participant and changing the audio and video settings. Nothing about screen sharing. Is this feature still not implemented?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this feature is not implemented yet. As a workaround you may use [Skype Preview](https://blogs.skype.com/news/2017/08/17/hello-desktops-meet-skype-preview/), which has the screen-sharing feature.

You may download the `.deb` package from [here](https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64-preview.deb) (download link found on [this page](https://www.skype.com/en/insider/)).

**NOTE:** Screen-sharing does **not** work in a Wayland session.

**Source:** This [OMG! Ubuntu! article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/08/skype-redesign-everyone-hates-now-available-linux)

Comment: @Rafael If you find this answer useful you may "accept" it by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it.